# Generic promise wrapper for async functions

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to declare a generic wrapper type for the external calls in my application.

Is there anyway to refer that something is a `Promise` inside of a type instead of explicitly using `Promise<T>`

My best attempt for a type:

```
type ExternalResult<T> = Promise<{
    success: boolean
    data?: T
    message?: string
}>
```

How I expect to use it:

```
const getStuff = async (): ExternalResult<Stuff> => {
    const data = await myFetchWrapper( /* stuff */ )

    if ( data ) {
        return {
            success: true,
            data: data,
        }
    } else {
        return {
            success: false,
            message: 'Failed to get stuff',
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get:

> TS1055: Type 'ExternalResult' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.

I know I could drop the `Promise<>` from my `ExternalResult` type and use `Promise<ExternalResult< Stuff >>`, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any compilation errors in ts playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCAnAdgQwDYCUIGcCuGwAPACoB8UAvFAApID2AtgJa4TEDeAUFH1AQDGgvLgBcUAEYMGGCGhS9+AEzTA0AfgmklfJqLQBzCFoHAkLFIe4Bfct26hIUAMrB8AMw-UpMuQoBuB0EGFFxgKGNgN09vGjRcEBRBKAAKAEoJeERUTBwCImIYr0oqSh4+JAh3VCgUCAB3OkZWdlSq3GpKDtTOIRFccShzfAgAGihVdQkPTHYJ-UGjCAkAIgALFlWbdPSgmyA

Comment: Try adding `-target es2015` to either your `tsc` invocation, or `"target": "es2015"` to your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @msbit 's answer works.

Answer (score -1):

According to the MDN documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> Return value.
> A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an exception thrown from, or uncaught within, the async function.

So try to wrap your return statements with Promise.resolve call:

```
if ( data ) {
    return Promise.resolve({
        success: true,
        data: data,
    });
} else {
    return Promise.resolve({
        success: false,
        message: 'Failed to get stuff',
    });
}
```